# How to remove node_modules form unstaged tab?

Tags: git, atom-editor

I have some unstaged files from node_modules in Git Tab. I want to remove them because there are too many files and I do not see the good ones. Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[Link for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MixxX.png)

I try too stange them all but it is not working. I can stage normal files but from node_modules/.bin etc it just stands there.

I have this .gitignore file:

```
/node_modules/*
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea
/.vscode
/.vagrant
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log
.env
.phpunit.result.cache
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably added node_modules/ to your index. Go to that directory using git bash and remove the node_modules directory from your index and commit that change:

```
git rm --cached -r node_modules
git commit -m "removing node_modules from index"
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed, I think the other method with git checkout Head works but This one was secure

Answer (score 0):

first
set following variables in .git/config:

```
> [core]
>     autocrlf = false
>     safecrlf = false
>     eol = crlf
```

then

then run `$ git checkout HEAD .`

1. Select what you wanted to remove
2. Right click and remove/discard

Comment: Thanks but why is there, is it important? Hope I do not discard something important. All of them are blanks but don't know why it appears there.

Comment: You have to discard only not important things ! beware. It can be just a line , event it appeared as changes. Sometimes this is an error in git pipeline

Comment: @AdrianKevin I'm not 100% sure this is what you're facing, but: If you've `git add`ed the files in the past, then adding them to `.gitignore` will not stop git from tracking them.

Comment: Ofc But how I know that and  why  I can't stage and push them the nodes files

Comment: An example, there are from .bin and empty and some webpack weird

Comment: What do you Think about CRLF will be replaced by LF, new lines I think Linux Windows or something

Comment: try to run `$ git checkout HEAD `